# Several Symfony projects in one database but different Postgres schemas

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to setup environment in which several Symfony REST API projects (microservices actually) live in single Postgres database but occupy different schemas in DB.

There is no problem to use `@ORM\Table` to define schema but I found out that `migration_versions` table is still living in `public` schema. And blindly hitting 'Yes' while applying migration in the second project just removes the table for the first one.

Of course, I could manually trim generated migration class not to allow execute `DROP TABLE` statement. But is it possible to setup Doctrine to use custom schema for storing `migration_versions` table thus completely isolating one project from the others within a single database?

Comment: Doctrine prefix does not apply to migrations table ? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to symfony Documentation, you can name migrations table on each of your project, maybe using the same prefix you use to separate your tables.

```
 # config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations
    table_name: 'migration_versions' // Use a custom name for each application ? 
    column_name: 'version'
    column_length: 14
    executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
    name: 'Application Migrations'
    # available in version >= 1.2. Possible values: "BY_YEAR", "BY_YEAR_AND_MONTH", false
    organize_migrations: false
    # available in version >= 1.3. Path to your custom migrations template
    custom_template: ~
    all_or_nothing: false
```

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Let's say your project tables start with **myproject_** prefix. To prevent migrations from removing your other tables, you can use doctrine dbal **schema_filter** property in your config.yml/doctrine.yml

### config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: "/^myproject_/"
```

According to symfony documentation : # If set to "/^sf2_/" all tables not prefixed with "sf2_" will be ignored by the schema tool. This is for custom tables which should not be altered automatically.

So that should do the trick for your use case

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use dot-notation in `table_name` property to move `migration_versions` in desired schema. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm... It may be strange by Doctrine generates `DROP TABLE` statements for neighbor project. Both for entity table and `migraion_versions_<project_name>`. Again, it could be wiped out manually. But why does Doctrine care too much about tables not related to current project?

Comment: Look at the last section of the documentation about the doctrine dbal filter property. It may do the trick if you think of a regular expression that says : any table name not starting with my project prefix ...

Comment: Looks like it works well only for the first time but when I switch back to first project and start adding properties to an entity and `./bin/console make:migration` it could not generate it because `Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "migration_versions_first" already exists` . "first" is a postfix for `migration_versions` table and prefix for entity tables created in "first" schema. Need some debugging trying to find out the actual reason.

Comment: Same situation with the second experiment project: while `make:migration` it wants to re-create `migration_versions_<project_postfix>` table despite of `table_name` properties set in `doctrine-migrations.yaml`

Comment: Did you try naming your migration table myproject_migration_version instead of migration_version_my_project ?

Answer (score 0):

For Doctrine Migration v3.x take care configuration has changed !

```
table_name: your_table_name
```

as been replaced by

```
table_storage:
    table_name: your_table_name
```

Doctrine migration documentation here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.3/reference/configuration.html

If you use doctrine-migration-bundle it will looks like

```
doctrine_migrations:
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: your_table_name
```

Doctrine migration bundle documentation here : https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#configuration